# clone with relcopy plugin stope select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-select2

i have the below relcopy plugin but when i run it with select2 v4 the second row select2 its not activating (drop not working)

```
/**
 * jQuery-Plugin "relCopy"
 * 
 * @version: 1.1.0, 25.02.2010
 * 
 * @author: Andres Vidal
 *          code@andresvidal.com
 *          http://www.andresvidal.com
 *
 * Instructions: Call $(selector).relCopy(options) on an element with a jQuery type selector 
 * defined in the attribute "rel" tag. This defines the DOM element to copy.
 * @example: $('a.copy').relCopy({limit: 5}); // <a href="example.com" class="copy" rel=".phone">Copy Phone</a>
 *
 * @param: string   excludeSelector - A jQuery selector used to exclude an element and its children
 * @param: integer  limit - The number of allowed copies. Default: 0 is unlimited
 * @param: string   append - HTML to attach at the end of each copy. Default: remove link
 * @param: string   copyClass - A class to attach to each copy
 * @param: boolean  clearInputs - Option to clear each copies text input fields or textarea
 * 
 */
(function($) {
    $.fn.relCopy = function(options) {
        var settings = jQuery.extend({
            excludeSelector: ".exclude",
            emptySelector: ".empty",
            copyClass: "copy",
            append: '',
            clearInputs: true,
            limit: 0 // 0 = unlimited
        }, options);
        settings.limit = parseInt(settings.limit);
        // loop each element
        this.each(function() {
            // set click action
            $(this).click(function() {
                var rel = $(this).attr('rel'); // rel in jquery selector format             
                var counter = $(rel).length;
                // stop limit
                if (settings.limit != 0 && counter >= settings.limit) {
                    return false;
                };
                var master = $(rel + ":first");
                var parent = $(master).parent();
                var clone = $(master).clone(true).addClass(settings.copyClass + counter).append(settings.append);
                //Remove Elements with excludeSelector
                if (settings.excludeSelector) {
                    $(clone).find(settings.excludeSelector).remove();
                };
                //Empty Elements with emptySelector
                if (settings.emptySelector) {
                    $(clone).find(settings.emptySelector).empty();
                };
                // Increment Clone IDs
                if ($(clone).attr('id')) {
                    var newid = $(clone).attr('id') + (counter + 1);
                    $(clone).attr('id', newid);
                };
                // Increment Clone Children IDs
                $(clone).find('[id]').each(function() {
                    var newid = $(this).attr('id') + (counter + 1);
                    $(this).attr('id', newid);
                });
                //Clear Inputs/Textarea
                if (settings.clearInputs) {
                    $(clone).find(':input').each(function() {
                        var type = $(this).attr('type');
                        switch (type)
                        {
                            case "button":
                                break;
                            case "reset":
                                break;
                            case "submit":
                                break;
                            case "checkbox":
                                $(this).attr('checked', '');
                                break;
                            default:
                                $(this).val("");
                        }
                    });
                };
                $(parent).find(rel + ':last').after(clone);
                return false;
            }); // end click action
        }); //end each loop
        return this; // return to jQuery
    };
})(jQuery);
```

select2 intiation code is

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $(".select2").select2({
                width: "100%" /*,minimumInputLength: 3*/ ,
                maximumInputLength: 3000000,
                maximumSelectionLength: 30,
                tokenSeparators: [",", " "]
            });
        }
```

i have tried several solution but all doesn't work, any one can assist me

Comment: Please add (edit) the tags [tag:jQuery] and [tag:select2] to the question.

Comment: I have add tag for the CSS as i after do some search i found the problem in the CSS related to Select2 CSS